# How to get values from a linked model for validation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I don't know how get other fields, linked by `OnetoOne` with `User` model, in the `clean` method. I have models Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   books = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

And I want validation in method clean:

```
class ProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
      fields = '__all__'
   def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super().clean()
      get_books = cleaned_data.get('books')
      #this I get error
```

I only get the default user model fields (username, first_name..) How get value from the field 'books'?

Comment: Is `ProfileForm` A model form? If yes have you mentioned `model` param in meta of `ProfileForm`

Comment: You should add `model = Profile` in the `Meta` class.

Comment: What are we looking to achieve here? There are two potential use-cases I can think of; either you are looking to create users, or update posts for an existing user.

Answer (score 0):

You're sub-classing Django's `UserCreationForm` that is meant to create a user, and operates on the `User` model. Inside this form, you will not get access to the `UserProfile` model instance.

As you can see from the Django source code, the `UserCreationForm` is restricted to the `User` model and exposes the fields that are present in the `User` model only

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)
```

The `clean` method thus correctly returns `username`, `first_name` e.t.c here